# Larave - Heroku: file does not exist

Tags: laravel, heroku, inertiajs

I have an application in laravel 9, in my local environment I can upload images without problem (amazon s3), but in my deployment in heroku I get this error when trying to get the image I am sending.

```
 <form action="/test-upload-file" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @csrf
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image">
    <button type="submit">Upload File</button>
</form>
```

this is my function

```
Route::post("/test-upload-file", function (Request $request) {
    $testFile = Storage::put('tests', $request->file('image'));

    dd($testFile);
});
```

this is the error I am getting

```
The "" file does not exist or is not readable.
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, it is for the PHP configuration of the server, just create a `.user.ini` configuration file in the `/public` folder.

```
post_max_size = 10M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
```